# how to retrieve data from blob column data using cx_oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, blob

I have stored binary data into the oracle database in the blob. But I am not able to retrieve the same data. Here is my code

```
app=input("\nEnter the name of the app: ")
username=input("\nEnter the username: ")
cur.execute("select password from passwordM where app=:va and username=:vu", va=app, vu=username)
if cur.fetchone()==None:
    print("\nNo entry exists with app: '{}' and username: '{}'\nCheck again and enter correct details!!".format(app,username))
    continue
for x in cur:
    ctext=x[0]
print(RSADecryption(ctext))
```

The attributes 'app' and 'username' are of type varchar2 and 'password' is blob.
And this is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MLI-22 Project\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    print(RSADecryption(ctext))
NameError: name 'ctext' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't quite understand what you are using BLOB for storing passwords, anyway you might want to use `utl_raw.cast_to_raw`

See this example

```
SQL> create table my_test ( c1 varchar2(1) , c2 blob ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 1 , empty_blob() ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> update my_test set c2=utl_raw.cast_to_raw ( 'MyPassword' ) ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from my_test ;

C
-
C2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
4D7950617373776F7264


SQL> select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(c2) from my_test ;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(C2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyPassword

SQL>
```

Including on Python cx_oracle 8.0 , perhaps you need to use blobdata = xxxx

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
textdata = f.read()

with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    imgdata = f.read()

cursor.execute("""
        insert into lob_tbl (id, c, b)
        values (:lobid, :clobdata, :blobdata)""",
        lobid=10, clobdata=textdata, blobdata=imgdata)
```

Althoug you did not provide any update statement in your code, you might try to apply directly utl_raw.cast_to_raw directly to the string which will be stored as blob.

On the other hand, and it is not properly related with the question itself, storing passwords this way is a really bad practice. You should look a DBMS_CRYPTO in order to store encrypted passwords using a key.

Comment: I am using the RSA algorithm with pycryptodome library. The encrypted data is in binary so that's why I am using blob.

Comment: have you tried to apply utl_raw.cast_to_raw to the blob before updating it ?

Comment: I have used bind varibales to insert data: `cur.execute("insert into passwordM (app, username, password) values(:v1, :v2, :v3)", v1=app, v2=username, v3=ciphertext)`

Comment: use this instead to see if it works:  cur.execute("insert into passwordM (app, username, password) values(:v1, :v2, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:v3) )", v1=app, v2=username, v3=ciphertext)

Answer (score 0):

I have got where I was doing the mistake. Because I have already called fetchone(), so x will be None. it works when I write like it like this:

```
app=input("\nenter the name of the app: ")
username=input("\nEnter the username: ")
cur.execute("select password from passwordM where app=:va and username=:vu", va=app, vu=username)
if cur.fetchone()==None:
   print("\nNo entry exists with app: '{}' and username: '{}'\nCheck again and enter correct details!!".format(app,username))
   continue
cur.execute("select password from passwordM where app=:va and username=:vu", va=app, vu=username)
for x in cur:
   ciphertext=x[0]
print(RSADecryption(ciphertext))
```

Comment: is this not the title of your question ??? --> how to update blob column data using cx_oracle?